# Get result set in plsql

Tags: plsql

am wondering if there already some rewriting suggestions to get functions such generating recurrence dates between two dates - generate_recurrences() from this link for recurrency [recurrency events](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/recurring_events.html)

in plsql? it returns a setof date, but in plsql i can't figure out how to get a resultset for dates and looping return next next_date, where next also returns a next date on a list.

I tried it to rewrite it in plsql but with only return of one date, because i can't find out how to return a resultset in plsql, that what i've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GENERATE_RECURRENCE( rec in VARCHAR2,
                                start_date in TIMESTAMP,
                                end_date in TIMESTAMP )
RETURN  TIMESTAMP
IS
    next_date TIMESTAMP := start_date;
    duration  INTERVAL  DAY TO SECOND;
    day       INTERVAL  DAY TO SECOND;
BEGIN
 IF recurs = 'none' THEN
    return next_date;
 elsif recurs = 'daily' then
    duration :=  INTERVAL '1' DAY ;
    while next_date <= end_date loop
     return next_date + duration;
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following pipelined function a while ago.  It's not **exactly** what you're asking for, but it gives you a resultset that's a range of dates, so you should be able to match it to your needs.

It requires you to create a type object to hold the return value and I used an existing object instead of creating a custom one.  So you should modify this to use an object just big enough (and use date type instead of string).  But the functionality does what you're asking for.

Enjoy!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_range_stream(start_date_in IN DATE,
                                             end_date_in   IN DATE) RETURN rpt_results_10_obj_type_type
    DETERMINISTIC
    PIPELINED IS
    /* 
        Parameters:     start_date_in - First date to return (truncated)
                        end_date_in   - Last date to return, inclusive

        Results:        date string formatted as MM/DD/YYYY

        Author:         Stew Stryker

        Usage:          SELECT to_date(text01, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS a_date
                          FROM TABLE(aeo.aeo_misc_tools.date_range_stream('01-MAR-2009', SYSDATE))
                        Returns a rows from starting date to current

        Requires the definition of the following object:

            CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rpt_results_10col_obj AS OBJECT
            (   seq_num NUMBER,
                place VARCHAR2(20),
                rep_info VARCHAR2(20),
                text01 VARCHAR2(512),
                text02 VARCHAR2(512),
                text03 VARCHAR2(512),
                text04 VARCHAR2(512),
                text05 VARCHAR2(512),
                text06 VARCHAR2(512),
                text07 VARCHAR2(512),
                text08 VARCHAR2(512),
                text09 VARCHAR2(512),
                text10 VARCHAR2(512));


    */
    cur_date DATE := trunc(start_date_in);
    date_row rpt_results_10col_obj := aeo.rpt_results_10col_obj(NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                NULL);
BEGIN
    WHILE cur_date <= trunc(end_date_in)
    LOOP
        date_row.text01 := TO_CHAR(cur_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        PIPE ROW(date_row);
        cur_date := cur_date + 1;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        RETURN;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('EXCEPTION IN aeo.aeo_misc_tools.date_range_stream - ' || SQLCODE || ': ' ||
                             SQLERRM);
        RAISE;
        RETURN;
END date_range_stream;
```

Comment: If you find this useful, I could use some reputation points. Hint hint.